# How can I pay my Bank of America credit card statement with my Bank of America checking account on the Bank of America website?

Tags: untagged

I want to pay my Bank of America credit card statement with my Bank of America checking account on the Bank of America website. My Bank of America credit card and my Bank of America checking account are on two different Bank of America online accounts.

On the Bank of America online account where my Bank of America credit card is, I see:

[image]

However, when trying to add my Bank of America checking account as a funding account, they don't accept Bank of America routing numbers.

[image]

> The routing number you entered doesn't match any banks within our directory. Make sure you're adding an account from another bank and you're entering the number correctly.

How can I pay my Bank of America credit card statement with my Bank of America checking account on the Bank of America website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot pay one's Bank of America credit card statement with one's  Bank of America checking account on the Bank of America website if one's Bank of America credit card and one's Bank of America checking account are on two different Bank of America online accounts: they have to be on the same account. That's a strange limitation, but this is compounded by the Bank of America online technical support (+1 800-933-6262).

The only solution is to move the one's Bank of America credit card statement and one's  Bank of America checking account into the same Bank of America online account. Then one can set up the auto-payment via https://billpay-ui.bankofamerica.com/imm/PaymentCenter/Index/8307:

[image]